# Parameter-dependent integral $\int_0^1\sin(a+\arcsin(x))dx$

Tags: integration

I am calculating this integral $I(a)=\int_0^1\sin(a+\arcsin(x))dx$. I was given the hint to use rules for calculating Parameter-dependent integrals, but I don't really know how to proceed.

My first guess was to use addition theorem:
$$
\begin{align} I(a) &= \int_0^1 \sin(a+\arcsin(x))dx
\\ &=\int_0^1 \sin(a)\cos(\arcsin(x))dx + \int_0^1 \cos(a)\sin(\arcsin(x))dx
\\ &=-\sin(a)\int_0^1 \cos(\arcsin(x))dx+\frac{\cos(a)}{2}
\end{align}
$$
I also calculated the derivative $I'(a)$ and get:
$$
I'(a)=-\int_0^1 \cos(a+\arcsin(x))dx=-\cos(a)\int_0^1 \cos(\arcsin(x))dx+\frac{\sin(a)}{2}
$$
I tried to expose $\int_0^1\cos(\arcsin(x))dx$ and get:
$$
I(a)\cos(a)=-I'(a)\sin(a)+\frac{1}{2}
$$
But after that I really don't know how to proceed.

Comment: $\cos(\arcsin(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $0\le x\le 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that from
$$I(a)\cos a+I'(a)\sin a=\frac12$$
we have
$$[I(a)\sin a]'=\frac{1}{2}$$
thus $$I(a)\sin a=\frac{a}{2}+c$$
or $$I(a)=(\frac{a}{2}+c)\csc a$$

Answer (score 1):

After you broke the initial integral with the $\sin{\left(a+b\right)}$ identity, notice that $\cos{\left(\arcsin{x}\right)}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.  Therefore, the integral can be turned into:
$$\int_0^1 \sin{a} \sqrt{1-x^2} dx + \frac{\cos{a}}{2}$$

The integral can be computed easily noting that the integral of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ frm $0$ to $1$ is a quarter circle of radius $1$:

$$\boxed{\frac{\pi \sin{a}}{4}+\frac{\cos{a}}{2}}$$

Comment: Is there any intuitive derivation of $cos(arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$? From where this equality comes?

Comment: From $\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta}=1 \implies \cos{\theta}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\theta}}$.  Now plug in  ${\theta}=\arcsin{x}$ to get $\cos{\arcsin{x}}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$